# How can I get the data from a child component in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

Im newbie in web development, and also in vue. My idea is to make a component that has some user input, like text, a selection from a combobox and a checkbox. This component should be genereted dinamically by the user, I mean, the user needs to be able to add more and more of this components in the web via the "+" button on the parent component:

```
// Child component
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Key:</p>
        <input type="text" v-model.trim="key">
        <p>Type:</p>
        <select name="type" v-model="type">
            <option value="Integer">Integer</option>
            <option value="String">String</option>
            <option value="List">List</option>
        </select>
        <p>Required:</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="required" v-model="required">
        <button>More options</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const key = ref('key');
const type = ref('Integer');
const required = ref(true);

defineExpose({
    'key':key,
    'type':type,
    'required':required
})

</script>

<style scoped>
.row {
    display: flex;
}
p{
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```

```
// ParentComponent
<template>
      <div>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
          <Row :is="item"/>
        </div>
        <button @click="addComponent">+</button>
        <button @click="logComponentsData"></button>
      </div>
</template>
    
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Row from './Row.vue';

const items = ref([]);

const addComponent = () => {
  items.value.push({});
};

</script>
```

I used refs and v-model and also a sort of rendering list that im not sure if it is correctly applied.

In the web I can se through the vue extension that the data is changing in my child components:
[website img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2z8n.png)

But I dont know how is the right or any way possible for me to log all the child components data (key, type, required) for later usage.

I may want to store that data on local storage later on.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: so you just want to log the data that the individual child component have into localstorage, right ? Im asking this becase "how can i get data from child component in vue3" seems to me like you want to know how you can access child component's data into parent component

Comment: @ht006 I want to be able to log the data, so later on I can guess how to store it on local storage, but, as you can see in the image "website img" there will be more than one instance of the component, it wont be an "individual child", so I don't know how to access to any of the created instances data.

Comment: if i understand correctly, you can just add some code in Row component that just logs data of that particular component in localstorage, that way each component will log its own data into localstorage. is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Well, the main idea was to not depend on local storage at first, I wanted to just log the data to learn how can I access to data from instances of a child component without local storage...

But yes, now I'm going for the local storage option.. I'm trying to figure out what is the best option to store the data of the multiple instances of the component. Also, I need to be able to update the data and delete it from local storage.

Comment: then just add onMounted hook on row component put logic that adds data when the component is first mounted. Then add watchers that will be responsible to update data in localstorage when something changes

Comment: Yes! Just did that with watchEffect inside the child component, updating every change, now trying to instance those components from local storage data when pressing f5...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Use `v-model` for the child component:

```
// ParentComponent
<template>
<div>{{items}}</div>
      <div>
        <div v-for="(_, index) in items" :key="index">
          <ChildComponent v-model="items[index]"/>
        </div>
        <button @click="addComponent">+</button>
      </div>
</template>
    
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';

const items = ref([]);

const addComponent = () => {
  items.value.push({key:'key', type:'Integer', required:true});
};

</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
// Child component
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Key:</p>
        <input type="text" v-model.trim="value.key">
        <p>Type:</p>
        <select name="type" v-model="value.type">
            <option value="Integer">Integer</option>
            <option value="String">String</option>
            <option value="List">List</option>
        </select>
        <p>Required:</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="required" v-model="value.required">
        <button>More options</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import {computed} from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({'modelValue':{type: Object, required:true}});
const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);

const value = computed({
  get(){ return props.modelValue; },
  set(val){ emit('update:modelValue', value.value); }
});

</script>

<style scoped>
.row {
    display: flex;
}
p{
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a much more simpler option than what I finally used. I used props and click/change functions to update the components in the LocalStorage from the parent component... A lot of lines compared to your solution to be honest, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want log the latest value of every item?

```js
// Child component
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <p>Key:</p>
    <input type="text" v-model.trim="data.key">
    <p>Type:</p>
    <select name="type" v-model="data.type">
      <option value="Integer">Integer</option>
      <option value="String">String</option>
      <option value="List">List</option>
    </select>
    <p>Required:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="required" v-model="data.required">
    <button>More options</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  data: {
    type: Object
  }
})
</script>
<style scoped>
.row {
    display: flex;
}
p{
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>

// ParentComponent
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <Row :data="item" />
    </div>
    <div><button @click="addComponent">+</button></div>
    <button @click="logComponentsData">logComponentsData</button>
  </div>
</template>
    
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import Row from './Row.vue';
const items = ref([]);
const addComponent = () => {
  items.value.push({ key: 'key', type: 'Integer', required: true });
};
function logComponentsData() {
  console.log( items)
}
</script>
```